# Upload on amazon s3 server from silverlight application and play it on silverlight player

Tags: amazon-s3

My application is in silverlight 4.0. I needed to upload video file on amazon s3 server. The size of the video is too large around 3 to 4 GB.

Right now i am using Amazonclient to upload video but,it takes too much time. So, I am thinking to develop one uploader for the same.

Is there any controls available in silverlight or any other way to upload this large amount of file on s3 server?

can anyone knows how to develop uploader in silverlight that can upload large amount of video file on s3 server. ?

Please Help me and give me your valuable suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

There is a [commercial Silverlight library](http://www.parentelement.com/products/slights3/) for uploading directly to Amazon S3, from the company ParentElement.